# Zoom simultaneously in two UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I need to have two UIImageView, both with zoom enabled, (I can use the typical UISCrollView technique) and whenever I zoom in in one of them will result to zoom in the other as well, in the same point and with the same zoom.

Here's an explicative video: https://youtu.be/Ft-Dt3fx3z8?t=29s

Do you know any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question, first solution zooming async without scrolling

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == _scrollView1)
        return self.imageView1;
    else
        return self.imageView2;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    if (scrollView == _scrollView1){
        [_scrollView2 setZoomScale:scale animated:YES];
        [_scrollView2 setContentOffset:_scrollView1.contentOffset animated:YES];
    }
    else if (scrollView == _scrollView2){
        [_scrollView1 setZoomScale:scale animated:YES];
        [_scrollView1 setContentOffset:_scrollView2.contentOffset animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Second, better solution with real time zooming and scrolling (viewForZoomingInScrollView is still needed)

```
- (void)matchScrollView:(UIScrollView *)first toScrollView:(UIScrollView *)second {
    CGPoint offset = first.contentOffset;
    offset.x = second.contentOffset.x;
    offset.y = second.contentOffset.y;
    [first setContentOffset:offset];
    [first setZoomScale:second.zoomScale];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if([scrollView isEqual:_scrollView1]) {
        [self matchScrollView:_scrollView2 toScrollView:_scrollView1];
    } else {
        [self matchScrollView:_scrollView1 toScrollView:_scrollView2];
    }
}
```